# Can a non-canadian outside of Canada obtain a SIN for the purpose of opening a business?

Tags: canada, business, citizenship

Can a non-Canadian outside of Canada obtain a Social Insurance Number [SIN](https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/services/sin.html) for the purpose of opening a business or are they only available for Canadians and people residing inside of Canada?

Comment: What do you mean by "opening a business"? You don't need a SIN to register or carry out businesses in Canada; you need one if you work in Canada or access government benefits as a resident in Canada.

Comment: According to https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/registering-your-business/bro-eligibility.html you need a SIN.

Comment: BRO isn't opening a business; it's for facilitated tax registration of businesses. Only Canadian citizens and permanent residents are eligible to use it (temporary residents in Canada cannot use it either since their SIN begins with 9). You can use the service of an authorized Canadian representative if necessary. But you also don't have to use the online service.